# How to pass String value from Service to Activity in android?

Tags: android, service, notifications

In my small android application I created a Service to receive some string from web server and i want to pass that string to my activity and display that in textview

I tried this 
Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();  

b.putString("key", ITEM);  
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

// In Activity

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String i = b.getString("key");
```

But it always forcefully closing the application

Please any one help me because i wasted one week for this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can we see that stack trace for the force close? It could be a few different things.

Comment: You should try not creating a bundle to give to the intent and just do intent.putExtras("key", "string value")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a completley new activity ? or are you trying to relaunch the default activity ?

I suggest to take a look at the Remote messenger sample.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample

This pretty much covers your needs to comunicate a service with an activity.